# Kestrel launchSettings.json on Release in NET.6 VS2022

Tags: release, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, kestrel

gRPS .NET 6 service on Release doesn't pick up applicationUrl from launchSettings.json and listens by default - localhost:5000 and 5001 for https. How and where to set up a release so that it picks up the launchSettings.json in VS2022?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` is used only for development environment. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#lsj):

> The `launchSettings.json` file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - Contains profile settings.

For non-development environment options check the [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0) article.

Also can be useful:

- [5 ways to set the URLs for an ASP.NET Core app](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/)
- [Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Perfect answer! But now I have even more questions, so I'm deploying the application on Linux, and there are only 3 lines in the official documentation on the link about it :). Thanks for the reply, I'll look into it further!

Comment: @UNRE Was glad to helpl! The approach is the same. You need to use one of the configuration sources - `appsettings.json`, environment variables, process arguments, custom/other providers.